# how to seperate admin and user in cakephp..?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I try to make a new blog. the admin and user logins works fine. My problem is whenever user make login ,he can access the other user iformation too. how to protect those files ??. thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [Authentication & Authorisation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html) and [Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make yourself comfortable with [**the asking guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question that helps readers to be able to reproduce your problem. Currently your question is very vague, and doesn't contain any specific programming related problem, which is usually considered offtopic on StackOverflow. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an attribute to your "Users" table, name this attribute "super_admin" and give it a "smallint" type with the size of 1 caracter so he can take only 1 or 0 as a value(Boolean).

The only thing you have to do is checking if the user is a SUPER ADMIN or Not.

For exemple:

```
 $user=$this->request->session()->read('Auth')['User'];

if($user->super_admin == 0)//Not an Admin
{
//Do some stuffs
}
```

Don't forget to update your "Users" Model when you add the "super_admin" attribute.

For mor info please check [AUTHENTIFICATION WITH CAKE PHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html)

GOOD LUCK :)